# How do I display only the projects/comments/etc. that belong to a user in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My Project Model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20101117094659
#
# Table name: projects
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  description :string(255)
#  designer_id :integer
#  client_id   :integer
#  notified    :boolean
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#  user_id     :integer
#

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stages
  has_many :uploads
  has_many :comments

end
```

The Projects Controller looks like this:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  filter_resource_access

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.xml
  def index
    @projects = Project.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @projects }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.xml
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @project }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  # GET /projects/new.xml
  def new
    @project = Project.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @project }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])     
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.xml
  def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@project, :notice => 'Project was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /projects/1
  # PUT /projects/1.xml
  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
        format.html { redirect_to(@project, :notice => 'Project was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.xml
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])    
    @project.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(projects_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

When a user logs in, and goes to clicks 'View all projects' which links to the index action of the projects controller, I want them to only see the projects that they are allowed to see.

The index view of the projects controller looks like this:

```
<h1>Listing projects</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to project.name, project %> | </td>
        <td><%= project.description %> | </td>


        <% if permitted_to? :edit, @project %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
        <% end %>

        <% if permitted_to? :destroy, @project %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<% if permitted_to? :create, Project.new %>
    <%= link_to 'New Project', new_project_path %>
<% end %>
```

I don't want you to do this for me, but could you walk through with me what I would need to do. i.e. do I need to add new columns to the tables, or do I create a new table and create a join between that new table and my users and projects model & tables?

Another thing to keep in mind, I have four major models that I want personalized to each user. Projects, comments, uploads, stages.

Oh, and I have a superuser that I want to be able to view all projects/comments/stages/uploads per user (both on a granular level, and on a high-level).

Would love to hear your thoughts.

Edit: Also, if you could possibly point me in the direction of some reading material that might help me with this entire process - I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add in your User model :

```
class User
  ...
  has_many :projects
end
```

And this should to the trick :

```
@projects = current_user.projects
```

It will work if you have a current_user method of course. Otherwise it's equivalent to (although I'm sure you don't want to pass the user_id) :

```
@projects = User.find(params[:id]).projects
```

You should really read the [rails tutorial book](http://railstutorial.org/book) or the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Hrmm....i guess the real question is how to set the user_id field when the project is being created. E.g. According to the Rails guide, I should do the following: `  @project = @user.projects.create(params[:project])` in my create action in projects controller. But that gives me a 'NoMethodError' for the method 'projects'. I realized that the user_id field is not being set in the db when the projects are being created - even though I have the associations setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
  @projects = Project.find_by_user_id(HOWEVER YOU KEEP YOUR USER ID)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @projects }
  end
end
```

This work only if user can only see projects they've created them self, as Mike answer.

In case you want a user to be able to access other project then the one he has created, you could use a [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association).  Where a table would contain ID of user and ID of project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add user_id in your project table than you can use above suggestions